# ASP.NET: if(!IsPostback) what is that in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, pageload

I want to set div to "display:none" on pageload in HTML when it haven't been loaded before, which in ASP.NET called if(!IsPostBack), i don't know what's called in HTML.

```
function startUP()
{
    document.getElementById('output').style.display = "none";
}

<body onload='startUP();'>

<div id='output'>
<p>hide me on load and show me onclick<p>
</div>

<button id='showOutput'/>
```

I don't know what it's called, so i tried to explain it.

Comment: I think you are approaching this the wrong way; JavaScript does not need to check if there is a PostBack event because it is run on the client, any Post events would occur outside it's scope.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function startUP() {
        document.getElementById('output').style.display = "none";
      }
    </script>
  </head>

<body onload='startUP();'>

<div id='output'>
  <p>hide me on load and show me onclick<p>
</div>  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah it works..
i have an online example, try take a look
[example](http://arcane-swift.dk/form.php)

Comment: @Thieryy Yeah, but i would like to show you what i am dealing with, it's because its in a form, where i am using a submit, and when i'm clicking submit, its like the website is reloading the page, i don't know why, and then its setting it to display:none again..

Comment: submit leads to a http post request, and an answer of the server, which leads to reload the page (normal working).

Comment: that's exactly what i mean, and then it reloads the page, and sets the output on display none again, so actually it is working, just need to do something so its only checking for if you have seen the page before.

Comment: So you have to pass a parameter in the url, which means 'pageAlreadySeen'

Comment: Yeah, i need something that checks if the page is already seen, so it doesn't reset everytime i click the button